# Is it possible to mount SOSS hinges with no gap?

Tags: tabletop, table-making, hinges

Given the below image represents using one of these SOSS-style hinge to hang doors, showing a gap between pieces such that the door can open without hindering itself.

[image: hinge cross section image and table]

Is it possible to mount the hinge such that we can have both pieces touching perfectly flush?
If it is possible I imagine that we would just inset the hinge ends further into the board an equal amount?

For example,Say I have a **101** hinge, the diagram shows **A** being 2.4mm with a gap between the pieces of 2.7mm (**B**). So to get a completely flush fold I would be required to increase **A** by 2.7/2 = 1.35mm on each leaf?

Comment: Yes. Look at the diagram and see where you'd 'add' wood, either in width of the frame or thickness in the door piece (with the hinge position appropriately offset). This would have to be done *very* carefully since as you know Soss hinges have zero adjustability. Most definitely something you'd need to try on scrap to make sure you have the positions dialled in!

Comment: The table of measurements state that measurement A cannot be exceeded. One would suggest this means the desired modification is not recommended/possible, yes? Wouldn't there be contact and undesired wear if the numbers are not followed?

Comment: If you were to increase A gap by 1.35 mm (setting it deeper), the face of the door when closed would no longer be flush with the exposed edge (the right mounting point).  The door would be set in by your 1.35 mm.  That is why the max A gap is 2.4 mm, increasing the A gap would force the door to be set in and not flush.

Comment: I think A does not need to be changed. Table you picture in other question must have gap in top when flat because C is fixed by hinge, no?